# regex fail2ban rules

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am setting up Fail2ban on my server, recently got a lots bad bots is crawling my site cause my SQL server down

From my Apache2 logs

```
51.255.65.13 - - [10/Dec/2017:12:03:19 +0800] "GET /crew/nm0935095-gary-winick HTTP/1.0" 200 17985 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
51.255.65.30 - - [10/Dec/2017:12:03:31 +0800] "GET /movie/tt0498567-summer-time-machine-blues HTTP/1.0" 200 17658 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
217.182.132.190 - - [10/Dec/2017:12:03:36 +0800] "GET /movie/tt1705064-genji-monogatari:-sennen-no-nazo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 17344 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"
```

how to create a failregex for "ahrefs.com" ?

Many Thanks

Comment: You don't want fail2ban, you want Apache rules to deny referrers. A simple google for `Apache deny referrer` will surface plenty of resources on the topic.

Comment: Thank you, this is working temporary, but I checked the log, the bot is still working after few 500 error, it still crawling my site :(

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch anything containing "ahrefs.com", your failregex would look as follows:

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.*ahrefs\.com.*
```

Where the `<HOST>` tag is built-in Fail2ban as an alias for `(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)`:

https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Apache